# Static class variable vs function variable. Is one more efficient?

Tags: c#, performance, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

I'm a bit obsessive about efficiency, but I've never been able to find a definitive answer to this question. Is one of these more efficient / better than the other, and if so why?

**Static class variable used in non-static function:**

```
public class Example {
    private static int index;

    private void Test() {
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

**Variable declared inside function:**

```
public class Example {
    private void Test() {
        int index = 0;
    }
}
```

The `index` variable will only be used by the `Test()` function.

Runtime speed is more important than memory usage. If the answer varies between languages then I'm specifically asking about C#.

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: You've potentially got 2 different behaviors. You're comparing apples with oranges. However, if `Test()` is the only method that's going to use `index`, create the variable in that method.

Comment: This isn't an efficiency question - it is a correctness question. They do *very different things*.

Comment: Since neither of your classes actually do anything at all; it is more efficient to just delete them both.

Comment: When the code runs with the variable declared in the function, does the program need to allocate memory each time the function is called? Compared to a static class-level variable, which is allocated once.

Comment: Local variables like that go on the stack which is basically free efficiency-wise. If I came across code like the first snippet at work, I'd want to strangle whoever wrote it.

Comment: That doesn't help me understand because "basically free" and "free" sound like they mean different things. I'm trying to find out which approach is "free" at runtime, or if both are, or neither.

Comment: What you're talking about is a microoptimization at best.

Comment: Correct. That's why I'm asking, so I can understand it. In the project I'm working on, one of these "micro" optimisations may be happening a few hundred times each frame.

Comment: I recommend you do some actual benchmarking. Have you read https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/?

Answer (score 1):

I think there would be no difference in performance, except you would be putting a bit of extra burden to the garbagecollector as you would be allocating more memory in the instance variables.

If you are thinking of doing multi-threading and performance is important, use the instance variable, instead of the static variable.

You did however peaked my interest and I wrote a simple program to do the test. The result of 1 million allocations of a static and instance variable have taken 3ms. I ran the test 5 times during the same runtime and below is the

Static test took 3 milliseconds.
Instance test took 3 milliseconds.
Static test took 3 milliseconds.
Instance test took 3 milliseconds.
Static test took 3 milliseconds.
Instance test took 3 milliseconds.
Static test took 3 milliseconds.
Instance test took 3 milliseconds.
Static test took 3 milliseconds.
Instance test took 3 milliseconds.

I have uploaded the code to my [github repository](https://github.com/igalnassi/ConsoleTestStaticPerformance/tree/master), specifically [Program.cs file](https://github.com/igalnassi/ConsoleTestStaticPerformance/blob/master/Program.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no dissertation in terms of speed increase in execution time or memory consumption, it is like that you compare apples and oranges, they are different, but both are fruits.

The only difference between your two examples is the static keyword, which avoids the need to instantiate, however, this does not affect the performance or optimize the code

The only thing you achieve with this is to modify the way in which you access the `index` variable